# Parameters in an Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am programming an application in VBA that uses ODBC and querying for large data sets. I have found that putting the SQL in a string - or concatenated strings - is messy and doesn't seem to work for anything over the standard string length.

I have taken the route of using the query builder and saving the query with parameters. I am attempting to access this query programatically. However, this query has 3 parameters and I am not having luck with articles and answers I have found.

Here is the code:

```
Dim qdf
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Kilometers")
qdf.Parameters("startDate").value = startDate
qdf.Parameters("endDate").value = endDate
qdf.Parameters("workshopCode").value = garageRst!ID

Set rs = kpidb.OpenRecordset("Kilometers")
```

I have the parameters in the sql statement called "Kilometers" like so:

```
PARAMETERS startDate DateTime, endDate DateTime, workshopCode Text ( 255 );
```

And in the statement use square brackets to denote the parameters. I also have them set up in the access tool for parameters.

When I run my code, Access is saying that it needs 3 parameters (error 3061)

Is this the way I should be achieving my end goal? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried prepending an `@` to each parameter name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to open your recordset using the QueryDef object you created. Your corrected code should look like:

```
Dim qdf
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Kilometers")
qdf.Parameters("startDate").value = startDate
qdf.Parameters("endDate").value = endDate
qdf.Parameters("workshopCode").value = garageRst!ID

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

Hope it helps. Good luck with your project.